# HTTP post to ASP MVC 3 from a client app

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP MVC 3 site that allows a user to submit some helpdesk information.  I also have a client app (WPF) that users should be able to submit helpdesk information from.  I would like to just do a HTTP POST to the same form that the user would use via the web site.

Is this possible?  I've tried using RestSharp but I keep getting a 401.2 from my site.

Thoughts?

My MVC controller action is something like:

```
//
// POST: helpdesk/submit
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(HelpDeskRequest helpDeskRequest)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to POST values to your controller action:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "Id", "123" },
        { "Name", "abc" },
    };
    var result = client.UploadValues(
        "http://www.domain.com/helpdesk/submit", 
        values
    );
}
```

and inside the action you will get:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(HelpDeskRequest helpDeskRequest)
{
    // helpDeskRequest.Id = 123;
    // helpDeskRequest.Name = "abc";
    ...
}
```

Comment: There were actually 2 problems.  This solves 1, the other was I had anonymous auth disabled, hence 401.